# Solve this number sequence: 20, 21, 21, 22, 12,?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Can you find the last number of this sequence; it may require a bit of a leap?

> 20, 21, 21, 22, 12, ?

Hint 1:

> "a bit of a leap" is a hint to what the sequence of numbers is based on, and doesn't refer to an actual leap in sequential numbers.

Hint 2:

> This number sequence is based on a series of numbers, which almost everyone is very familiar with. There's even a popular rhyme about it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's

> 12

and they're related to

> the number of days in each month of a *leap* year: 29+**2**=31 (January), 29+**0**=29 (February), etc. The last two digits correspond to November (29+**1**=30) and December (29+**2**=31).

Comment: Well done :D. I should have probably added in better hints from the start.

Answer (score 16):

The last number is

> 1202

And so the sequence is

> 20 21 21 22 12 1202

Because

> The digits of the number sequence form a palindrome. The large gap between 12 and 1202 is what is referred to by "it may require a bit of a leap."

Comment: Good answer, but unfortunately it's incorrect. The pattern becoming a palindrome is purely coincidental, and in fact adding the two digits to the end of the sequence would also impact the initial numbers as well. Well done though, for seeing the hints at the start, however you may want to rethink what "it may require a bit of a leap" means.

Answer (score 6):

Series would be

> 20,21,21,22,12,13.
> Next number is increasing by one simply.

Potential clarification offered by *[Tarius](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/35881/tarius)*.

> I think @Kriti is splitting the sequence up into three component parts: 20,21 ; 21,22 ; 12,13, where the second number of each part is the increase of the first respectively.

Comment: Please explain why you think this is the case...

Comment: But 22 increased by one isn't 12?

Comment: I think @Kriti is splitting the sequence up into three component parts: 20,21 ; 21,22 ; 12,13, where the second number of each part is the increase of the first respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The rule for 20, 21, 21, 22, 12, 21... is:

> First figure in each number is the number of different digits of the previous issue.
>  The second digit is the number of twos in the previous issue.

Comment: The second 2 in 22 doesn't play by the rule for the second digit, does it? The previous number is 21, which has a single 2.